# why the output print false while it should be true?

Tags: python

I have to write a code use regulare expression. the outputs print both false while it should be true and false.

```
def match_the_words(pattern):

    the_words = ["hello", "shello", "qwello", "jello", "jelly", "jelloy", "hellboy"]
    for word in the_words:
        if not re.fullmatch(pattern, word):
            return False
    return True

print(match_the_words("hello"))

print(match_the_words("hell"))
```

Comment: What should the code do? Why should the output be what you say?

Answer (score 1):

If any of the words dont match the function return false because the return false is in the loop and the negative condition, so if the condition is false once it returns false.
 Reverse the `return False` and `return True`.
In general you should try debugging because you would've understood it better and more importantly **by yourself**, which is always good to do.